# App is deployed to heroku but returns a server error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have my application working perfectly when I run it locally. However, once it was deployed to Heroku, the server stopped returning the data and returns a 500 code. All of my code can be found [here](https://github.com/reaganclayton/weatherUP) and the live application (not functioning) is [here](https://fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com/).

EDIT:
Here are the heroku logs:

```
2021-03-06T04:00:59.416851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=0a279e6e-c6d0-4bf8-ac4d-45d85c914e4a fwd="174.45.175.167" 
dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=50ms status=200 bytes=1401 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:00:59.672729+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/app.71b734f2.js" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=68509950-00e2-4f0d-84ea-3a96cf0dcbc1 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=62457 protocol=https2021-03-06T04:01:00.023258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/app.badeae52.css" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=603ee68a-bc30-4c7e-8177-3e3c0f3fa712 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=200 bytes=3523 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:01:00.035863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-vendors.e9c4f783.js" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=8e857b3a-b40d-4ad8-a1aa-cb8dc6d3b15a fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=39ms status=200 bytes=501256 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:01:04.003747+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/result/tyler" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=45020e4f-61d5-419d-9a51-f61ccb06b257 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=500 bytes=284 protocol=https        
2021-03-06T04:01:08.110920+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/result/henderson" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=e9f739c3-36cb-4d3e-a480-e93d0784ea66 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=284 protocol=https    
2021-03-06T04:01:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user reaganclayton1995@gmail.com
2021-03-06T04:01:38.112111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/result/tyler" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=f8a0dd9a-a033-430a-8249-6f433b6066a5 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=45ms status=500 bytes=284 protocol=https        
2021-03-06T04:01:40.977816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/result/tyler" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=305a750b-8ca6-486c-9cee-a7b9b3e64891 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=500 bytes=284 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:01:46.859981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=738c1e2e-ed83-4fef-86e3-52813667b798 fwd="174.45.175.167" 
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:01:47.095156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/app.71b734f2.js" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=aa992042-2411-439d-b982-e180501f2e07 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https   
2021-03-06T04:01:47.101684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/app.badeae52.css" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=aad26a97-869d-450b-9d14-b1deac43a470 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30ms status=200 bytes=3523 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:01:47.157018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-vendors.e9c4f783.js" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=4eb14331-e0c3-4127-b691-0f036cca30a4 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=59ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:02:07.327105+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 36a0a5b6 by user reaganclayton1995@gmail.com
2021-03-06T04:02:07.327105+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user reaganclayton1995@gmail.com
2021-03-06T04:02:07.516033+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-03-06T04:02:07.541614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-03-06T04:02:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-03-06T04:02:09.003004+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-03-06T04:02:09.247345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-03-06T04:02:09.633378+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-06T04:02:12.908565+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-06T04:02:12.908594+00:00 app[web.1]: > weatherup@1.0.0 start
2021-03-06T04:02:12.908594+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server
2021-03-06T04:02:12.908595+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-06T04:02:13.113839+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running in production mode on port 39626
2021-03-06T04:02:13.917299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-06T04:09:34.447563+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=b591ded0-7f1a-4c14-a1e2-7f856a2e45aa fwd="54.164.83.156" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=1401 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:10:06.594714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=b063d8b0-d361-40a2-a0e8-85b2ac937292 fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=321 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:11:00.259797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/result/tyler" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=216b9449-8ad7-4bf4-8780-99d3db9ea0c0 fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=284 protocol=https
2021-03-06T04:11:03.661150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/result/henderson" host=fast-shore-66611.herokuapp.com request_id=9b656dd6-dccc-4271-a507-2181e358193d fwd="174.45.175.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=284 protocol=https
```

EDIT 2:
It turns out that I had my `config.env` added to my `.gitignore`, so my server didn't have access to my environment variables to make the API call. Now I am wondering if taking it out of the `.gitignore` is going to allow users to access the file, which is what I don't want.

Comment: You're going to need to get more information to determine the problem. Give this a shot: `$ heroku logs -t -a fast-shore-66611`.

Comment: I added the most recent logs in an edit

Comment: Is your source repository public?  If so, putting your config.env in it will also make it public.  If not, then `config.env` is as secure as any of your other source files.  Note: it is natural to have to deploy some things to your server environment manually or with some different deployment process (such as database passwords) because you don't want to store them the same place you store your source code because they have a different level of privilege applied to them.

Comment: Heroku now has access to the config.env but I removed that file from my public GitHub repo. I hope that answers what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

[Follows these steps which is given in image, That's a right way to deploy app on Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ5eN.png)